# Нажатие сочетания в selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Как нажимать сочетания клавиш в selenium? Нужно нажать сочетание Ctrl + end. Я пробовал так

```
driver.key_down(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).send_down(Keys.END)
```

и так

```
driver.key_down(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).send_down(Keys.END).perform()
```

Не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пошлите просто END будет тот же эффект. А если другое сочетание то тоже в примере

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")

body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.send_keys(Keys.END)
#body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a')
```