# Как правильно нажимать клавиши в selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, selenium

мне нужно нажать ctrl и стрелку влево одновременно в selenium
Пробовал вот так

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.Keys import Keys

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.send_keys(Keys.CONTROLL + Keys.ARROW_RIGTH)
action.perform()
```

Но этот код просто ничего не делает. Идей почему это не работает у меня нет. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нажатие сочетания в selenium python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1125630/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-selenium-python)

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ, вот код:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.Keys import Keys

driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.ARROW_RIGTH)
```